# What classifier imply a volume?

Tags: measure-word

I know that you can use 盒 to suggest that there is a collection of the following noun, such as 一盒麻将牌 (a box of mahjong tiles) and I was wondering which other classifiers I can use for a similar effect, for instance a bouquet of flowers or something.

Comment: 束：see iciba：bouquet of flowers：束鲜花； 束花； 束兰花：捧花

Comment: Thanks. :) Bouquet was just an example though, I'm curious if there are more.

Comment: Measure/count words in Chinese are like preposition/conjunction words in English - there's a lot of them and usage is largely idiomatic.

Comment: I haven't been able to find a complete list of classifiers, but this might help you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Chinese_classifiers -- it's only a list of common ones, not a full list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few classifiers:

- 束 shù: bundle, bouquet; 一束花
- 袋 dài: bag
- 包 bāo: package; 一包烟
- 副 fù: set
- 套 tào: set
- 堆 duī: pile
- 坨 tuó: lump
- 群 qún: group
- 组 zǔ: group, set, lineage
- 碗 wǎn: bowl
- 罐 guàn: can, jug, bottle
- 壶 hú: pot
- 家 jiā: certain group of people
- 管 guǎn: tube
- 类 lèi: collection of objects
- 笔 bǐ: sum of money; 一笔钱
- 团 tuán: ball, spherical collection
- 股 gǔ: gaseous or liquid flow